# How to access a dom element in a directive from page controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I try to access an element that is in a directive, but my controller doesn't find it, how to do it ? In the example below, variable canvas in controller MyCtrl is null.

**Edit:**
Concretely my directive is a custom collapse, so the content into it can be various. For example, I have a view which display informations that are in those collapses made by my directive, and user can edit it. By the way, the business  logic is in the view controller, it handles data load and send user modification. Code below edited to be more accurate.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <collapsible-div title="Open Me">
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></span>
    </collapsible-div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",['$scope', function($scope) {

    var canvas  = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    /* Some code do draw image in my canvas... */

}]);
```

directive:

```
myApp.directive('collapsibleDiv', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            /* Some code to make my collapsible div how I want... */
            /* This has nothing to deal with content, this directive can store any kind of content */
        },
        templateUrl: 'collapsible.html'
    };
});
```

**Final solution:**
A controller shouldn't access directive dom, I may use a more modular approach using a new directive to handle my canvas, my html looks like this now, and my controller is empty:

```
<collapsible-div title="Open Me">
    <my-canvas></my-canvas>
</collapsible-div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more background information about why you want to access the element? One of the main goals of Angular is to eliminate the need to control the DOM in your controller. I'd guess that there's a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do without opposing Angular's paradigm.

Comment: Should be `collapsibleDiv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having problems understanding the differences between a directive and a controller. I suggest you to go deeper on those concepts.

On your specific problem, as you are using a directive, and also because you should manage all DOM operations on a directive, the place to put it will be the link function of your directive.

In this case, something like this:

```
myApp.directive('directive', function(){
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
        link : directiveLinkFunction
    };

    function directiveLinkFunction( scope, element, attrs ) {

      // element -> the DOM element that hold the directive.
      // for different selection, use the jQuery lite API

    }

    return directive;
});
```

You then need to use some other strategies to share data between controller and directive, but thats is a whole different topic.

Main point -> do all DOM manipulations on a directive.

Comment: my directive has nothing to deal with its content, the directive is used to display various informations, which are managed by the controller, is it bad way ?

Comment: Yes, you have to think about a modular approach all the time. If you are gonna have a directive for that, then dont break things and put everything on the directive. Another possibility, could be to create two difference directives: one for the collapse and another for the canvas. This will give you more modularity and separation of concerns.

Comment: okay thanks it is clear, so in my controller I will only load my data, then I will use a directive to display a canvas which take in parametter data loaded by my controller. Finally it will looks like this: <collapsible-div title="Open Me"><my-image data='controllerVariable'></my-image></collapsible-div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use **link** in the directive, then you will have access to the element declarated. Example:

```
myApp.directive('directive', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              //Here you have control over element
              console.log(element); 
              //for example, you can create events on the element
              element.bind('click', function(){
                     //put your code here
              });

        }
    };
});
```